# JDialog has an implicit minimum width on Windows 10, how to bypass it?

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, jdialog

I seem to not be able to make my JDialog smaller than a minimum width on Windows 10 (observed java 7 & above). Minimum width seems to be 230px, impossible to make it smaller, even when specifying a new minimum size as shown in the code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestDialog {
    public TestDialog() {
        JDialog testDialog = new JDialog();
        testDialog.setSize(new Dimension(10, 100));
        testDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 100));
        testDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        testDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestDialog();
    }
}
```

[image: minimum width jdialog]

How can I force the JDialog to be smaller than that ?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is to undecorate it

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) What's the purpose of such a small dialog?

Comment: 1) edited, 2) displaying data in narrow, stacked-up JLabels (in a column)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue is the default look-and feel. 
When I tried setting a different decoration style after setting `testDialog.setUndecorated( true );` as suggested by  [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53511455/3992939) I got a very narrow decorated dialog:

```
    class TestDialog {

    public TestDialog() {
        JDialog testDialog = new JDialog();
        testDialog.setUndecorated( true );
        testDialog.getRootPane( ).setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG );
        testDialog.getContentPane().add(makeContent());
        testDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        testDialog.pack();
        testDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel makeContent(){
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        pane.add(new JLabel("  1 "));
        pane.add(new JLabel("  2 "));
        pane.add(new JLabel("  3 "));
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        new TestDialog();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, setting the dialog un-decorated would work:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JDialog testDialog = new JDialog();
    testDialog.setUndecorated(true);  // ****** here ******
    testDialog.setSize(new Dimension(10, 100));
    testDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 100));
    testDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    testDialog.setVisible(true);
});
```

Not sure if other solutions exist

Comment: This removes all windows decorations (icon, titlebar, close button), I still need to be able to move the window around and/or close it.

Comment: @Bastien: but don't you see that those are the components that are forcing your dialog to be a certain minimum width? You can add a mouse listener to the dialog if you need to move it, as well as other things to allow you to close it, but otherwise you can't have your cake and eat it too, I'm afraid.

Comment: yes, this is obviously a windows 10 decoration issue and that's why I mentioned the OS in the original post. And I understand I can add a mouseListener, this is what I might end up doing, but it all seems like re-inventing the wheel when the windows UI should handle this in the case of a JDialog.